Topologically symmetric models of $\mathsf{ZFA}$
The standard construction of permutation models (i.e. models of $\mathsf{ZFA}$ involves choosing some collection of atoms $A$, a group $G$ of permutations on these atoms, and then a normal filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $G$. The model is then specified as a restriction of the universe $\mathbb{V}(A)$ to those elements which are hereditarily symmetric with respect to the $G,\mathcal{F}$ system.
Recently I've been thinking about the idea of generalizing this construction. In particular, let $G$ be a topological group. Instead of specifying a filter on $G$, we instead stipulate that an element of $\mathbb{V}(A)$ is an element of the restricted universe if every element of its transitive closure has an open stabilizer in the topology of $G$. In this way, we can obtain a structure in which we can violate various choice principles. We can generalize this even further by considering topological monoids instead of topological groups. The only pressing question which remains is whether or not such a structure would continue to be a model of $\mathsf{ZFA}$. Certain axioms come for free: For instance extensionality is obvious since the specified structure is transitive, and pairing certainly holds because the pairwise intersection of open sets is open.
However, I have been struggling with the intuition behind which other properties we are required to impose on the topology we choose on the group/monoid in order to satisfy the other axioms of $\mathsf{ZFA}$. Any insight into this would be appreciated. Any references to papers/articles considering similar constructions are greatly appreciated as well.

@NoahSchweber Since the stabilizers are subgroups of $G$, they can't quite be disjoint. More relevant though is the fact that any two open subgroups together generate an open subgroup.

@AndreasBlass Whoops, I had the wrong picture in my head.

A possibly useful  reformulation of "every element of $X$ has an open stabilizer" is that the action of $G$ on $X$ is continuous (as a map $G\times X\to X$) with respect to the discrete topology on  $X$.

Unfortunately, the acronym ZFA is ambiguous, since some people mean set theory with atoms i.e. urelements, and some people mean set theory with antifoundation AFA. In the atomic case, it is also ambiguous about whether collection+separation is included, or merely replacement, and whether there is a predicate for being an atom or whether they are indiscernible with the empty set.

@Joel: That is unfortunate, but ZFA is fairly the standard in the literature on permutation models.
